# Why is linkedin site both traffic in http 1.1 and http 2

Tags: linkedin-api, omniauth-linkedin

#linkedin Our firm is having accessibility issue when accessing your site.
Trying to understand why we are seeing Http1.1. and http2 traffic from the site.
This is affecting users when trying to open multiple tabs for m the linkedin site.
Can someone from your networking or infosec side assist this with this issue.
It is affecting productivity at a large scale.

Tried to open multiple tabs in #Linkedin and pages fail to load

Comment: I don't think you can at companies like this here.